# Merge/Combine two 'overlay' layers in GIMP

Tags: gimp, layers, image-editing

Working on my image in GIMP, I have the following configuration:

Top Layer (Normal)
Layer 1 (Overlay)
Layer 2 (Overlay)
Background

Since Layer 1 and Layer 2 are both of the same blend mode and transparency I would like to 'combine' them into one layer; doing this however results in a very different effect to what I want. (Understandable when looking at the Overlay equation: http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-layer-modes.html)

**Is it possible to combine two layers, such that the effect of overlaying the resultant layer is equivalent to overlaying the first layer, then the second?
If so, how do I do it?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but the answer is no as far as I know...

The only exception of course is when the two layers don't "overlap" one another (i.e. they don't have non transparent parts one above the other) - in that case change both layers to normal mode, merge them, and then change the merged result to be in overlay mode.

Comment: Yes thats all i've been able to do so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same effect by turning off layers until it looks the way you want it and then selecting new from visible under the layer menu. It won't effect your existing layers at all.